# How do I make links open in a new tab using the category link widget?

Tags: widgets, link

I'm using the following code to create inline text links to categories based on their ID:

```
{{widget type="catalog/category_widget_link" anchor_text="Some text" title="Some text" template="catalog/category/widget/link/link_inline.phtml" id_path="category/###"}}
```

This way, the links go directly to the store category without having to use the URL. But the problem is, I need these links to open in a new browser tab. Since I'm not using `<a href="">` to create the links, I can't use the HTML target attribute to direct them to open in a new tab.

Does Magento have a target attribute equivalent for these types of links created with this widget?

Answer (score 1):

You can just copy to your theme folder and edit this `catalog/category/widget/link/link_inline.phtml` template:

```
<span class="widget widget-category-link-inline"><a target="_blank" <?php echo $this->getLinkAttributes() ?>><span><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAnchorText()) ?></span></a></span>
```

Also you can create your custom template with this code and set path to this template in widget tag:

```
{{widget .. template="path_to_your/template.phtml" .. }}
```